# Only plotting two of four diagrams in yyaxes

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to use a `plotyy` and hold on to plot four diagrams in two y axes and it did not work.

Can anybody see where is the problem?

It only plots the first two diagrams:

```
load dexpan2Cp;
x1=dexpan2Cp(:,2);
x1=x1/3600;
y1=((dexpan2Cp(:,3)+dexpan2Cp(:,4))/2000)*32.5;
load Dexpan2_2C;
x2=Dexpan2_2C(:,1);
x2=x2/3600;
y2=Dexpan2_2C(:,2);
A = importdata('Scan Session94-Dexpan19.txt','\t',5); 
Dexpan19p=A.data;
save('Dexpan19p.mat','Dexpan19p');
x3=Dexpan19p(:,2);
x3=x3/3600;
y3=((Dexpan19p(:,3)+Dexpan19p(:,4))/2000)*32.5;
load Dexpan19C;
x4=Dexpan19C(:,1);
x4=x4/3600;
y4=Dexpan19C(:,2)+3.3;
x1 = x1(x1<115.7); y1 = y1(1: length(x1) , :);
x2 = x2(x2<115.7); y2 = y2(1: length(x2), :);
x3 = x3(x3<115.7); y3 = y3(1: length(x3), :);
x4 = x4(x4<115.7); y4 = y4(1: length(x4), :);
hold off;
figure;
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2);
set(h1,'g',y1,'DisplayName','1');
set(h2,'b',y2,'DisplayName','2e');
hold(ax(1),'on');
plot(ax(1),x3,y3,'r',y3,'DisplayName','3');
hold(ax(2),'on');
plot(ax(2),x4,y4,'k',y4,'DisplayName','4');
xlabel('Time (h)');
ylabel(ax(1),' Pressure (MPa)');
ylabel(ax(2),'Tempereture (°C)');
legend('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using invalid syntax, and not telling us what errors you are receiving when executing your code.  In particular, your code errors out after plotting the first two lines -- hence why you are only getting 2 lines plotted.

To make it work, four of your lines should be changed to,

```
set(h1,'Color','g','DisplayName','1');
set(h2,'Color','b','DisplayName','2e');
plot(ax(1),x3,y3,'Color','r','DisplayName','3');
plot(ax(2),x4,y4,'Color','k','DisplayName','4');
```